# How to use jpa entity classes in server project and client project from shared library when client calls web service from server?

Tags: java, web-services, jpa, client-server

I am using netbeans and generate entity classes from database with it.

I have a project that runs on server computer and provides web services using this entity classes. These classes are used in other manager classes that use and transform the information from the entity classes.

I have to use these manager classes both in server project and in client project. If I create a library containing the manager and entity classes, I can use them in both projects. The problem is that in the client project for the web service client call a new classes are generated so I will have duplicated logic in the client - two classes will correspond to one thing - first the entity class from the library and second the class generated from the web service client.

How can I elegantly solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the most elegant solution but you can create layer of DTO objects (layer of abstraction). Then you would include and use these DTOs in your library together with your manager classes. You would than have to map Entity classes on server side to those DTO objects. And also map generated objects on client side to those DTO objects.
The advantage is that your manager clasess are now independent on source of data. As it should be because you are using them once with Entity classes from DB and once with objects returned from Web services. This way it seems cleaner to me.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be writing your client dependent code against interfaces, not classes.  [See this reference, which demonstrates how to specify an explicit interface that both the client and server must implement](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html).

That said: if you have JAXB classes on the server side that you must (re)use on the client side, then you'll not be able to leverage the advantages of the generated client-side artifacts.  This doesn't mean you can't use the JAXB classes.

Use the JAX-WS Dispatch API to send a web service request from your client using the JAXB artifacts (WSDL optional!) directly.

Here's a reference [describing the requirements](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_jaxwsdynclient.html).

Here are some examples:

- [For CFX](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html#HowdoIdevelopaclient?-JAXWSDispatchAPIs)
- [For Glassfish's Metro](http://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.6/docs/ch03.html#section-71379735580733)